# How parent() and closest() work in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, append, rows

I want simply to add a `row` table after another `row` when the latter is clicked, so I used the following code (actually I am using this code in a visualforce page).

```
function queryAndUpdateLead() { 
        var a = $('[id$=ibrahim]').closest('tr')
                .after('<tr><td>New Content 1</td><td>\
                        <a href="#">New Content 2</a></td></tr>');
}
```

The problem here is that this row is added after all the existing rows in the table and when I used the `length` property to check the number of elements in `a` I get always 2 (I have initially 2 rows)

```
alert('a.length') // this shows 2
```

What I want is to get **only** the direct parent row and not all the the existing rows but I do not know why it does not work?

EDIT: THE HTML CODE RENDERED BY SALESFORCE SERVER:

```
<tbody id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6:tb">
<tr class="dataRow even first" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);} " onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);} ">
**<td id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6:0:ibrahim" class="dataCell " onclick="queryAndUpdateLead();" colspan="1">**
<td id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6:0:j_id7" class="dataCell " colspan="1">
<td id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6:0:j_id8" class="dataCell " colspan="1">
<td id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6:0:j_id9" class="dataCell " colspan="1">
<td id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6:0:j_id10" class="dataCell " colspan="1">
</tr>
<tr class="dataRow odd last" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);} " onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);} ">
<td id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6:1:ibrahim" class="dataCell " onclick="queryAndUpdateLead();" colspan="1">
<td id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6:1:j_id7" class="dataCell " colspan="1">
<td id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6:1:j_id8" class="dataCell " colspan="1">
<td id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6:1:j_id9" class="dataCell " colspan="1">
<td id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id6:1:j_id10" class="dataCell " colspan="1">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do all the rows have an id ending in "ibrahim"? Because that's the selector you used.

Comment: No , only one row is named Ibrahim

Comment: Then please show your HTML; and enough jQuery to reproduce your issue, otherwise we can only play guessing games.

Comment: yes, but the html code is long as it's rendered by the salesforce server

Comment: i updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have collection of `$('[id$=ibrahim]')` elements, you need to use `$(this)` to find closest `tr` of currently clicked element and insert that content after:

```
function queryAndUpdateLead() { 
        var $(this).closest('tr')
                .after('<tr><td>New Content 1</td><td>\
                        <a href="#">New Content 2</a></td></tr>');
}
```